# Having an issue compiling a function

Tags: c++

I am having an issue compiling a function that is similar other successfully compiled funcions.  Here is the error:

```
University.cpp: In function ‘bool ValidCRN(long int)’:
University.cpp:113: error: ‘Courses’ was not declared in this scope
University.cpp:23: error: ‘int University::index’ is protected
University.cpp:117: error: within this context
University.cpp:22: error: ‘bool University::success’ is protected
University.cpp:118: error: within this context
University.cpp:21: error: ‘bool University::failure’ is protected
University.cpp:122: error: within this context
```

Here is my University.h:

```
#ifndef UNIVERSITY_H
#define UNIVERSITY_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "Department.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Course.h"
#include "Faculty.h"
#include "Person.h"

class University
{
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const vector<Department>& d);
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Department& department);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<Faculty>& f);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Faculty& faculty);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<Student>& s);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& student);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Course& course);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<Course>& c);

 protected:
  vector<Department> Departments;
  vector<Student> Students;
  vector<Course> Courses;
  vector<Faculty> Faculties;
  static bool failure;
  static bool success;
  static int index;

 public:
  bool CreateNewDepartment(string dName, string dLocation, long dChairID);
  bool ValidFaculty(long dChairID);
  bool ValidDepartID(long fDepartID);
  bool CreateNewFaculty(string pName, string pEmail, string pAddress, string pDateOfBirth, string pGender,float fSalary, int fYearOfExp, long fDepartID);
  bool CreateNewStudent(string pName, string pEmail, string pAddress, string pDateOfBirth, string pGender, int sYearOfStudy, string sMajor, long sAdvisorID);
  bool CreateNewCourse(int cMaxAvailableSeats, string cName, long cDepartID, long cAssignedSeats, long cIsTaughtBy);
  bool ValidMajor(string sMajor);
  bool ValidAdvisor(long sAdvisorID);
  bool ValidInstructor(long cIsTaughtBy);
  bool RemoveADepartment(long ID);
  bool ValidDID(long ID);
  bool RemoveAStudent(long ID);
  bool ValidSID(long ID);
  bool RemoveACourse(long CRN);
  bool ValidCRN(long CRN);
  bool RemoveAFaculty(long ID);
  bool ValidFID(long ID);
};
#endif
```

My University.cpp file containing four functions(the first two have no compile error):

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "University.h"

bool University::failure = false;
bool University::success = true;
int University::index;  //This is line 23

bool University::RemoveADepartment(long ID)
{
  if(ValidDID(ID) == University::success)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < Departments.size(); i++)
        Departments.erase(Departments.begin() + University::index);
      cout << "Department " << ID << " deleted." << endl;
      cout << Departments;
      return University::success;
    }
  return University::failure;
}

bool University::ValidDID(long ID)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Departments.size(); i++)
   {
      if(Departments[i].ID == ID)
        {
          University::index = i;
          return University::success;
        }
   }
  cout << "Department not found." << endl;
  return University::failure;
}

bool University::RemoveACourse(long CRN)
{
  if (ValidCRN(CRN) == University::success)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < Courses.size(); i++)  
        Courses.erase(Courses.begin() + University::index);
      cout << "Course " << CRN << " deleted." << endl;
      return University::success;
    }
  return University::failure;
}

bool ValidCRN(long CRN)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Courses.size(); i++)  //This is Line 113
    {
      if (Courses[i].CRN == CRN)
        {
          University::index = i; //This is Line 117
          return University::success;
        }
    }
  cout << "Course " << CRN << " not found." <<endl;
  return University::failure;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting these errors.  My courses vector cannot be the issue.  I was able to successfully populate it in a function (not listed).  And I have been using my static variables in my other functions without any issues.  Any idea why I'm getting this?

Answer (score 4):

`ValidCRN` is declared as a member of `University` so

```
bool ValidCRN(long CRN)
```

in your cpp needs to be

```
bool University::ValidCRN(long CRN)
```

The reason for the compiler errors is that your code declares a function of global scope called `ValidCRN`.  This function isn't a member of `University` but tries to access protected members of that class.

Comment: I feel like an idiot!  I have been staring at this over and over and not once did it occur for me to look at that.

Comment: Most bugs are obvious with the benefit of hindsight :).  For future reference, errors like `int University::index is protected` are a good hint that a function isn't being treated as part of your class.

Comment: A good way to make this kind of error more obvious is to use a distinguisher for member variables, e.g. "m_courses", static variables "s_localCounter" and globals "g_shuttingDown".

Comment: I'll take your suggestions under advisement!